# How to resolve google app engine latency?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, paas, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Our project is running on the Google App Engine standard environment with auto-scaling configured as mentioned below. Warm up requests are enabled in the app and we are using Google Endpoints service. However, I am facing a latency issue in the different scenarios.
Environment: **Java 8**, Instance type: **F4_1G**
Configuration for autoscaling: 
    **min-instances: 2
    max-concurrent-requests: 80
    min-pending-latency: 6s
    max-pending-latency: 10s**

I tested with JMeter with configuration of sending **85 asynchronous requests** with a **ramp up period of 10 seconds**.
From the application logs I can notice that appengine takes a long time to serve the request.Below are the questions I have

1.Most of the requests are failing because of time exceed. In image 1, we can spot that the request takes 88.2 seconds. I know that AppEngine auto scaling has a 60 seconds request timeout limit. But we have configured autoscaling with a minimum 2 instances and there is no restriction for max-instance. The AppEngine Instance should handle the request otherwise AppEngine should scale up to handle the request. **Why is it not happening?**
[Image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6vp1.png)

2. While scaling up, the request takes 43.6 seconds. In image 2, we are able to see that the request came at 20:27:01:663 IST and the first line of API execution starts at 20:27:40:407 IST. **What is happening in between time? Can I get a log for this period?**
   [Image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96eoI.png)
3. After the scaleup, subsequent requests also take a very long time to serve. For instance an API request usually gets completed within 2 seconds. In image 3, we can note that API takes 42.4s without loading-request process and then request comes at 20:27:01:728 IST. The first line of API execution starts at 20:27:40:708 IST. **What is happening in between time?** 
   [Image_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imLr7.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think that is related with Java 8 runtime that takes long time to deploy a new instance, because java is a heavy runtime.

The deploy time exceed 60s and your unattended requests will be ended by timeout.

I think that you can improve your you escalation strategy, for example try to start your service with more instances and add this option "[target_throughput_utilization](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements)" in order to start to raise a new instance before hit your 80 concurrent requests

the documentation state that:
'When the number of concurrent requests reaches a value equal to max-concurrent-requests times target-throughput-utilization, the scheduler starts a new instance.'

```
min-instances: 4 
max-concurrent-requests: 80
target_throughput_utilization:0.75
min-pending-latency: 6s 
max-pending-latency: 10s
```

In my example the new instance will start when the actual instance has  (80 X 0.75) 60 concurrent requests

Comment: Thanks @JorgeHDZ. In my configuration, we have 2 min instance and it has capable to manage(80 * 0.5 Minimum value of target-throughput-utilization) **40 request per instance**. Then I have configured 10s max pending latency and we didn't mention max instance, min_idle_instances, max_idle_instances So are all automatic type. As per google document, it should handle the 85 concurrent request. **But I don't why is it not happening?** I have configured system logs(debug mode). From the logs I can notice that App engine context loading takes only 4to6 sec. So I thought is **not related to Java8**.

Comment: are you trying set up all configurations on default mode?

Comment: I m not trying for default configuration. @JorgeHDZ.

Comment: please try to use the default config maybe your configurations are affecting the way to attend your requests

Comment: I have tried with default config also but also I'm facing same issue.

Comment: i think that the next step is file a case with GCP support, they will be able to help you and view in more detail the behavior of your App Engine service,

please follow this link to file a new case

https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers